# Python/Pandas - How do I rename a column header in a DataFrame, without losing the existing data within the column header?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading multiple HTML tables off of one website, and one of the tables erroneously pulls the first line of data within the table as the header for the DataFrame.

This code:

```
list_addition = pd.read_html('https://www.espn.com/college-football/team/stats/_/id/87/season/2020')
list_addition[8].head()
```

Produces the following table:

```
    Index  Drew White LB
    0      Asmar Bilal LB
    1      Jeremiah Owusu-Koramoah LB
    2      Alohi Gilman S
    3      Jalen Elliott S
    4      Khalid Kareem DL
```

I want to be able to move the first header of data into the DataFrame, and rename the column, without losing the data.  See below for ideal output:

```
    Index  Name
    0      Drew White LB
    1      Asmar Bilal LB
    2      Jeremiah Owusu-Koramoah LB
    3      Alohi Gilman S
    4      Jalen Elliott S
```

Configuring the pd.read_html to exclude headers is not an option, as I am pulling multiple tables from the same website, and all other tables pull headers correctly.  I am additionally unable to perform list_addition.rename(columns="Name"), as I do not want to lose the first row of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that the easiest way is to make a new column "Name", using `shift` or offset to move the data down one row.  Then you hard-code assign the column label to row[0].

Each of these steps is documented quite well in many places, so I'll leave the coding as an exercise for the reader.  :-)